# Setting up a loop to Parse a JSON response

Tags: javascript, json, loops

I am currently using the wunderground api as a tool to learn JS. I have the below code to parse data from the JSON response that I am getting but this is an hourly forecast and I would like to parse 36 hours the below code only parses 1 hour. I know there is an easier way to do it other than creating variables for all 36 hours. If anyone could point me in the right direction I would appreciate it.

**How I am currently parsing the JSON:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#hourly").click(function() {
var t = document.getElementById("zip").value;

  $.ajax({
  url : "http://api.wunderground.com/api/MYKEY/hourly/q/" + t + ".json",
  dataType : "jsonp",
  success : function(parsed_json) {
var h0day = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["FCTTIME"]['weekday_name_abbrev'];
 var h0time = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["FCTTIME"]["civil"]; 
     var h0temp = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["temp"]["english"];
     var h0icon = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["icon_url"];
     var h0condition = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["condition"];
```

**Sample JSON response that I am parsing:**

```
{
  "response": {
  "version":"0.1",
  "termsofService":"http://www.wunderground.com/weather/api/d/terms.html",
  "features": {
  "hourly": 1
  }
    }
        ,
    "hourly_forecast": [
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        "hour": "21","hour_padded": "21","min": "00","sec": "0","year": "2014","mon": "1","mon_padded": "01","mon_abbrev": "Jan","mday": "26","mday_padded": "26","yday": "25","isdst": "0","epoch": "1390788000","pretty": "9:00 PM EST on January 26, 2014","civil": "9:00 PM","month_name": "January","month_name_abbrev": "Jan","weekday_name": "Sunday","weekday_name_night": "Sunday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Sun","weekday_name_unlang": "Sunday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Sunday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": ""
        },
        "temp": {"english": "24", "metric": "-3"},
        "dewpoint": {"english": "15", "metric": "-9"},
        "condition": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_cloudy.gif",
        "fctcode": "4",
        "sky": "94",
        "wspd": {"english": "8", "metric": "13"},
        "wdir": {"dir": "South", "degrees": "190"},
        "wx": "",
        "uvi": "0",
        "humidity": "67",
        "windchill": {"english": "16", "metric": "-8"},
        "heatindex": {"english": "-9998", "metric": "-9998"},
        "feelslike": {"english": "16", "metric": "-8"},
        "qpf": {"english": "", "metric": ""},
        "snow": {"english": "", "metric": ""},
        "pop": "10",
        "mslp": {"english": "29.87", "metric": "1011"}
        }
        ,
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        "hour": "22","hour_padded": "22","min": "00","sec": "0","year": "2014","mon": "1","mon_padded": "01","mon_abbrev": "Jan","mday": "26","mday_padded": "26","yday": "25","isdst": "0","epoch": "1390791600","pretty": "10:00 PM EST on January 26, 2014","civil": "10:00 PM","month_name": "January","month_name_abbrev": "Jan","weekday_name": "Sunday","weekday_name_night": "Sunday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Sun","weekday_name_unlang": "Sunday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Sunday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": ""
        },
        "temp": {"english": "25", "metric": "-3"},
        "dewpoint": {"english": "16", "metric": "-8"},
        "condition": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_cloudy.gif",
        "fctcode": "4",
        "sky": "94",
        "wspd": {"english": "9", "metric": "14"},
        "wdir": {"dir": "SSW", "degrees": "199"},
        "wx": "",
        "uvi": "0",
        "humidity": "70",
        "windchill": {"english": "16", "metric": "-8"},
        "heatindex": {"english": "-9998", "metric": "-9998"},
        "feelslike": {"english": "16", "metric": "-8"},
        "qpf": {"english": "0.00", "metric": "0.00"},
        "snow": {"english": "", "metric": ""},
        "pop": "10",
        "mslp": {"english": "29.82", "metric": "1009"}
        }
        ,
        {
        "FCTTIME": {
        "hour": "23","hour_padded": "23","min": "00","sec": "0","year": "2014","mon": "1","mon_padded": "01","mon_abbrev": "Jan","mday": "26","mday_padded": "26","yday": "25","isdst": "0","epoch": "1390795200","pretty": "11:00 PM EST on January 26, 2014","civil": "11:00 PM","month_name": "January","month_name_abbrev": "Jan","weekday_name": "Sunday","weekday_name_night": "Sunday Night","weekday_name_abbrev": "Sun","weekday_name_unlang": "Sunday","weekday_name_night_unlang": "Sunday Night","ampm": "PM","tz": "","age": ""
        },
        "temp": {"english": "26", "metric": "-2"},
        "dewpoint": {"english": "17", "metric": "-7"},
        "condition": "Overcast",
        "icon": "cloudy",
        "icon_url":"http://icons-ak.wxug.com/i/c/k/nt_cloudy.gif",
        "fctcode": "4",
        "sky": "94",
        "wspd": {"english": "9", "metric": "14"},
        "wdir": {"dir": "SSW", "degrees": "199"},
        "wx": "",
        "uvi": "0",
        "humidity": "70",
        "windchill": {"english": "18", "metric": "-7"},
        "heatindex": {"english": "-9998", "metric": "-9998"},
        "feelslike": {"english": "18", "metric": "-7"},
        "qpf": {"english": "", "metric": ""},
        "snow": {"english": "", "metric": ""},
        "pop": "10",
        "mslp": {"english": "29.82", "metric": "1009"}
        }
        ,
```

**... and so on.**

Comment: I think it would really depend upon what you want to do with the data. Are you setting those vars to save you time typing of the whole `parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["icon_url"];` section?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your json, it looks like `hourly_forecast` is an array, so you should be able to index it just like any other array. So, instead of:

```
 var h0day = parsed_json['hourly_forecast']["0"]["FCTTIME"]['weekday_name_abbrev'];
```

You should be able to do:

```
 var h0day = parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.weekday_name_abbrev;
```

where `i` is a variable in a `for` loop:

```
 success : function(parsed_json) {
     // check we have at least 36 entries
     var j = parsed_json.hourly_forcast.length < 36 ? parsed_json.hourly_forcast.length : 36;
     for(var i=0; i<j; i++) {
         var h0day = parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.weekday_name_abbrev;
         //...etc...
         // now do something with those parsed values...
     }
 }
```

Now if you actually need those values stored, then I'd suggesting using an array and pushing values into the array...

```
var myParsedData = [];
```

And now in you success function, I would store the values as objects:

```
     for(var i=0; i<j; i++) {
         myParsedData.push({
             hday: parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.weekday_name_abbrev,
             htime: parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].FCTTIME.civil,
             htemp: parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].temp.english,
             hicon: parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].icon_url
             hcondition: parsed_json.hourly_forecast[i].condition
         });
     }
```

And to access them later you can just do:

```
console.log(myParsedData[0].hday);
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I could do something like that. I was hoping someone could point me into the right direction for how to implement it.